# Is the thermostat in a room heater meant for room temperature control or for heater protection?

Tags: heat

I've an Intermatic Heatwave 1500W heater with me.The heater has 3 modes of operation: FAN, WARM(746W) & HOT(1490W).

The heater functions pretty normal in both FAN and WARM mode. But the moment I switch to HOT mode the heater activates the thermostat and turns off quickly and turns back ON after 30 secs or so.

My room temp is like 70F, in WARM mode the temp rose to 128F and in HOT mode it varied in two runs between 142F to 155F before the thermostat activates. The thermostat is a simple bimetallic one placed just behind the grill/ in front of the coil(white square shaped stuff with two wires as shown in picture).

While I could run in WARM mode, but as it becomes very cold in morning the WARM mode isn't sufficient. Does shorting the thermostat cause any issues? I plan to do this only if the response is " its just for room temperature control only".
[image: Internal]

[image: Label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thermostat knows nothing about the temperature elsewhere than in the heater box. Thus it's for protection. You can use the switches to get a little control over the room temperature. DO NOT short the thermostat nor try to modify it to make the cut-off to happen in higher temperature.

Buy more clothes or another heater. You can also make a timer to switch the heater on earlier. If your heater is on unattended, be sure that nobody can cover or otherwise make it dangerous while you sleep.

Comment: Usually, thermostats like this are placed in the incoming air stream and act somewhat like a room temp control. It is also providing safety to prevent overheating either when the fan is not working, incoming air is blocked, or the ambient air coming into the heater is too high.  One way to prevent the problem you are having is get get another fan to augment the air movement. DO NOT bypass the safety, especially on heating appliances.

Comment: @user287001 No I don't run my heater while I'm asleep no matter even if its a new one. Always a bad idea.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because like about 8 years back I had a nichrome wire England made 240V room heater (a friend gave it). Though it was a pain in the a** because it was 240V and there was only like one outlet in my bedroom(A/C outlet).All it had was a switch to turn on the second heater rod. It didn't have any sort of thermostat whatsoever. It ran well for more than 15 years until one of the nichrome wires melted off. 
Back to the question,so if that heater could run without a thermostat I was thinking why this heater wouldn't do it?BTW this is just a curious question mate.

Answer (score 1):

It is for heater protection.

Especially if the airflow gets blocked or reduced.